# stop stripping result of :session for python print statement

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, python

Since default value for `:result` header is **value** print statement will only 
show with `:result output`

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output
  print('  hello')
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
:   hello
```

but same thing in session is trimming *whitespace* trailing and preciding like python `str.strip()` method.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output :session test
  print('  hello')
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: hello
```

according to manual in [Results-of-Evaluation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html) **verbatim** which should Interpret literally seem only to work with **value** as stated in manual's usage example: ‘:results value verbatim’ will not show output of print.
How to stop the output being trimmed in session.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results value verbatim :session test
  print('  hello')
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
```

Comment: I don't know how to fix this, but using `value` won't work:  `For languages like Python, an explicit return statement is mandatory when using ‘:results value’. Result is the value returned by the last statement in the code block`

Comment: `s = "     hello"` and putting `s` on the last line with `:results value` does work though, but not a desirable solution

Comment: Quick question - Why did you choose to use `:session` header?

Comment: @Melioratus because i needed to carry my session around in many code blocks, above is the showing root cause of inconstant behavior.

Comment: Thanks! I thought this was the reason. Just to clarify, the problem is created due `org-trim` and you're using `:session` to share and/or combine code from seperate blocks that are not using `#+NAME:` or `:noweb-ref` headers correct? If the only reason for using `:session` is to combine code from separate blocks then using literate programming features instead of `:session` might also be a viable alternative solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editorial comment: Session handling (at least with python) is very much a hack: there are markers inserted to signal where the current output ends, the code has to wait to make sure that all the output has been... ahem ... output, any errors that creep through somehow may be reported as part of the output, etc.

That said, you might want to try the following "fix": in the file `ob-python.el`, lines 332ff, you will see a block of code that looks something like this:

```
      (mapconcat
        #'org-trim
        (butlast
         (org-babel-comint-with-output
             (session org-babel-python-eoe-indicator t body)
           (funcall input-body body)
           (funcall send-wait) (funcall send-wait)
           (insert org-babel-python-eoe-indicator)
           (funcall send-wait))
         2) "\n")))
```

Try replacing that `org-trim` with `identity` and reloading with `M-x load-file RET ob-python.el RET` (you might want to byte-compile it, but try it before doing so: you might want to beat a hasty retreat first to the original code).

There is no warranty, not even implied, on either the original code or the modified code. If you get errors, try deleting the session and starting it up again. If you still get errors, maybe change it back and live with the current problems.

Comment: i edited ob-python.el and byte-complie it, works!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to NickD's answer is to not use `:session` header to share code between blocks but instead use `:noweb-ref` syntax to combine code blocks.

> **How does this literate programming answer even work?**
>
> - The first three python blocks have the `:noweb-ref my-code` header added.
> - The python code from the first three python blocks are combined in top to bottom order and assigned to the noweb reference named `my-code`.
> - The fourth python block headers are `:noweb yes :results output` thereby bypassing `org-trim` issue by not using `:session` header.
> - When the fourth code block is executed, the `:noweb yes` header tells org-mode to substitute the `«my-code»` string for lines of code named in `my-code` noweb reference and then executes the updated code block.

#### Answer

- Example code to bypass `org-trim` issue in `ob-python.el` by not using `:session` header but still combining and/or sharing code between seperate code blocks:

  Save the following code example into an new org-mode file and then close and open the new file in emacs.

  > **Note:** When you open the new org-mode file, you will be prompted to accept the new values for `org-babel-noweb-wrap-start: "«"; org-babel-noweb-wrap-end: "»";`. Please type `y` to accept new values temporarily. Otherwise the example code will try to use the default values of `<<` and `>>` instead.

  ```
  # -*- mode: org; org-babel-noweb-wrap-start: "«"; org-babel-noweb-wrap-end: "»"; -*-
  # 
  # To prevent syntax highlighting conflicts with "<<" and ">>" in your source code I recommend setting variables org-babel-noweb-wrap-start to "«" and org-babel-noweb-wrap-end to "»" in your default emacs configuration.
  #
  # TIP: To create the "«" character use the key chord C-x 8 <
  # TIP: To create the "»" character use the key chord C-x 8 >
  # TIP: Add "-*- mode: org; org-babel-noweb-wrap-start: "«"; org-babel-noweb-wrap-end: "»"; -*-" to top of your org file just in case another user doesn't want to reset their default values.

  * Learning Python Syntax with Literate Programming in org-mode

  In your python script do the following:

  1. Define a variable named ~the_message~ in python syntax.

     #+BEGIN_SRC python :noweb-ref my-code
       the_message='  hello'
     #+END_SRC

  2. Define a function named ~greeting~ which takes a single parameter named ~msg~ and prints the ~msg~ in python syntax.

     #+BEGIN_SRC python :noweb-ref my-code
       #
       # Define greeting function
       #
       def greeting(msg):
           print msg
     #+END_SRC

  3. Call the ~greeting~ function using the ~the_message~ variable in python syntax.

     #+BEGIN_SRC python :noweb-ref my-code
       #
       # Call greeting function
       #
       greeting(the_message)
     #+END_SRC

  4. Execute your python script and you should see the following output.

     #+BEGIN_SRC python :noweb yes :results output
       «my-code»
     #+END_SRC

     #+RESULTS:
     :   hello
  ```

---

> **The code in this answer was tested using:**
>
> **emacs version:** GNU Emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.22.10)
>   **org-mode version:** 9.1.2
>   **python version:** 2.7.13

Comment: Very nice answer (but why not python3?)

Comment: @NickD - LOL - Good point! Unfortunately, I don't have python3 installed under cygwin64 yet. Unfortunately, I'm waiting to upgrade everything I have running under cygwin64, i.e. emacs, ruby, python, guile, etc... so I only have to get a single sign-off/approval/security audit for cygwin64 installations at work.

Comment: @Melioratus noweb-ref works for small sequence of code blocks. Intermediate state are hard to inspect resulting always to look for final block because tag (<<>>) ref copies block when executing which is quite contrary what session does. Similar to jupyter blocks, ob-ipython might do that in emacs which i haven't explored much.

Comment: @rho - To inspect the intermediate states I usually do `C-c C-v v` on last code block to combine the separate blocks and then start the python interpreter and `C-c C-c` to have buffer evaluated in the interpreter. This provides similar side by side views as session without using the `:session` header. Please keep in mind the answer uses simplest example of noweb syntax. There other ways to use noweb that easily scale to encompass several hundred of code blocks which contain up to a thousand of lines of code in each block.